# Does Flash pre-define any keyCode constants?

Tags: actionscript-3, constants, keycode

I would have expected, given the way Adobe seems to do things, that you could reference some of the non-ASCII keycodes using a static constant, for example `KeyCode.UP_KEY`. Am I dreaming? Or do you just assume 38 will be the up key in perpetuity..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `Keyboard` class

`Keyboard.UP` will refer to the up key, `Keyboard.DOWN` to the down key, and so on.

See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Keyboard.html for more key codes.

Comment: You are so very right. Thanks. Don't know why it was so hard to find (for me) in the Adobe docs. Should have been right there alongside the keyboard events....

Comment: Don't fault you for that. Adobe's docs are a pain in the arse to go through, and incomplete or incorrect in quite a few places :P