# Flash 8 key.isDown codes

Tags: flash, flash-8

I came to ask some way to get the numbers to be able to use the different keys of the keyboard in `flash` with `key.isDown`

I use the following:

```
if (Key.isDown (83))
```

**83** is the number defined to the **S** key, but on the other hand if I change the defined key to **83** instead of being **D** as it should be, it's the **T**.

And that's why I'm looking directly for a text file or page that gives me all the codes of each key on the keyboard directly, I'd be grateful if someone has what I'm looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Flash pre-define any keyCode constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110073/does-flash-pre-define-any-keycode-constants)

Comment: @Crocsx You link is for AS3, not for AS1/2.

Comment: You will probably find the answer here: https://books.google.ru/books?id=QgVpqNTuz5QC&pg=PA247&lpg=PA247&dq=as2+key+class&source=bl&ots=L3E3se55mi&sig=ACfU3U1v7Db6x_5_ZOTp181dUxctBwpAzg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjwsom6mJXmAhXDtYsKHYhAAMUQ6AEwA3oECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=as2%20key%20class&f=false